# Join array of object to new array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data array object like this:

```js
const data = [
  {Name: "dian", Job: "programmer"},
  {Name: "dian", Job: "gamer"},
  {Name: "candra", Job: "programmer"},
]
```

---

My goal is to create new data where a have same value join b.

Example output:

```js
const new_data = [
  {Name: "dian", Jobs: [{Job: "programmer"}, {Job: "gamer"}]},
  {Name: "candra", Jobs: [{Job: "programmer"}]},
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what did you try? You're expected to at least try and we can help if you have issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `reduce`.

```js
const data = [
  { Name: "dian", Job: "programer" },
  { Name: "dian", Job: "gamers" },
  { Name: "candra", Job: "programer" }
];

const output = Object.values(data.reduce((a, { Name, Job }, i) => {
  if (!a[Name]) {
    a[Name] = { Name, Jobs: [] };
  }
  a[Name].Jobs.push({ Job });
  return a;

}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achive your goal. From the documentation:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

One possible solution:

```js
const data = [
  {Name:'dian', Job:'programer'}, 
  {Name:'dian', Job:'gamers'}, 
  {Name:'candra', Job:'programer'}
];

const result = data.reduce((a, current) => {
  const found = a.find(f => f.Name === current.Name);
  
  if (found) {
     found.Jobs.push({Job: current.Job});
  } else {
     a.push({
      Name: current.Name,
      Jobs: [
        { Job: current.Job }
      ]
     });
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function modifyArray(data) {
    function getNewObject(data) {
        const newObject = {
            Name: data.Name
        };
        Object.keys(data).filter(key => key !== 'Name').forEach(key => {
             newObject[key+'s'] = [];
             newObject[key+'s'].push({
                 [key]: data[key]
             });
        });
        
        return newObject;
    }
    
    function appendData(obj, data) {
        Object.keys(data).filter(key => key !== 'Name').forEach(key => {
             obj[key+'s'].push({
                 [key]: data[key]
             });
        });
    }
    
    const reqArray = [];
    data.forEach(d => {
        const objToModify = reqArray.find(a => a.Name === d.Name);
        if (!objToModify) {
            reqArray.push(getNewObject(d));
        } else {
            appendData(objToModify, d);
        }
    });
    
    return reqArray;
}

let data =[ 
    {Name:'dian', Job:'programer' }, 
    {Name:'dian', Job:'gamers' }, 
    {Name:'candra', Job:'programer' }
];

console.log(modifyArray(data));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely appropriate here.  Please add at least a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```js
const combineJobs = (data) =>
  Object .values (data .reduce (
    (a, {Name, Job}, _, __, curr = a [Name] || {Name, jobs: []}) => 
      ({... a, [Name]: ({... curr, jobs: [... curr .jobs, {Job}]})}),
    {}
  ))

const data = [{Name: "dian", Job: "programmer"}, {Name: "dian", Job: "gamer"}, {Name: "candra", Job: "programmer"}]


console .log (combineJobs (data))
```

We simply fold our objects into a structure that looks like

```
{
  dian: {Name: 'dian', jobs: [Job:'programer'}, {Job: 'gamer'}]},
  candra: {Name: 'candra', jobs: [Job:'programer'}]},
}
```

then use `Object .values` to turn it into an appropriate array.

One advantage of this technique is that if your data actually has additional fields not displayed in the question (imagine you have `age`, and `avatar` properties as well, for instance), you can extend it easily using a rest parameter:

```js
const combineJobs = (data) =>
  Object .values (data .reduce (
    (a, {Name, Job, ...rest}, _, __, curr = a [Name] || {Name, jobs: [], ...rest}) => 
//                  ^^^^^^^                                              ^^^^^^^
      ({... a, [Name]: ({... curr, jobs: [... curr .jobs, {Job}]})}),
    {}
  ))
```

and all those additional parameters would be included.